# comparing and changing 2 values in the dataset then outputting via repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, repeater

I need to define what a child is:

I need to write something like `var parent = categoryID == ParentCategoryID = 0`

Here is my ASCX control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    categoriesBLL categoriesLogic2 = new categoriesBLL();
    rptCategories.DataSource = categoriesLogic2.GetCategories();
    rptCategories.DataBind();

}
```

I am display the values from a query which show up like this:

```
<ul class="categories">
<li>Computers</li>
<li>Hardware</li>
<li>Software</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see hardware and software should be sub categories but they show up in the same UL block as just another LI.

**My Dataset looks like this:**

[image]

I have a query which will determine the sub categories here:

```
SELECT        c1.CategoryID, c2.ParentCategoryID, 
              c1.Name, c2.Name AS ParentName, 
              c1.Published, c1.Deleted, c1.PictureID

FROM          Nop_Category AS c1 INNER JOIN
              Nop_Category AS c2 ON c1.ParentCategoryID = c2.CategoryID

WHERE        (c1.Deleted = 0) 
AND          (c1.Published = 1) 
AND          (c1.ParentCategoryID = @ParentCategoryID)
```

But how to pass the value for a category into my dataset for it to return the results?
I then need to create a new ul li:

```
<ul class="sub-category">
<li>Hardware</li>
<li>Software</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That query looks rather familiar  :)

Comment: All credit for the query goes to @ChrisGessler

Comment: To get child records, you'll have to figure out which parent the user clicked on, and pass that into your GetCategories(parentId) method.  But you don't have enough info your question.  Post your form code and your GetCategories() method as well.  Maybe that would be enough.

Comment: They wont be clicking, i want the menu to load like www.vango.co.uk the top level eg, Tents is are the category and the sub categories are the things inside.

Comment: You might not be "clicking", but there's an event firing to load the subcategories.  It would highly depend on how you're loading your resultset.  If you're grabbing all categories, you'll have to use (i.e.) linq to set the DataSource to just top categories. Or, you'll need to return multiple recordsets, parent / childofParent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a stored procedure and out the sql query in it also this proc will take parameter @ParentCategoryID
   and return result you want
2. Right Click on your .xsd and Add Query
3. In "Choose Command Type"
   Dialog  select use exisitng stored procedure Select the stored
   procedure you created in step 1
4. Give the method a name you prefer e.g. GetSubCategoriesByParentId
5. Click Finish

Now you can use the method in your code like this Nop_CategoryTableAdapter.GetSubCategoriesByParentId and pass the parentCategoryId to get subcategories back

Comment: Im just trying to visualise this, it needs to be like the menu on http://www.vango.co.uk

Comment: My answer covers the question "But how to pass the value for a category into my dataset for it to return the results?" Once you got the results then you can create a new ui li

Comment: Yes, i understand. I will try this when i get home. Its just a hobby of mine to learn. Nothing work related.

Comment: My understanding is i create the SP and then in the code i pass the value for the onHover parentID to the SP which will return its child categories. Or write a for each loop which does it for every single parentID eliminating the onHover event.